# Adding images to a javascript plugin

Tags: javascript, css, image

I'm creating an image gallery using the Galleria plugin.

I'm customised the styling of the gallery, editing css within the .js file, but there's one task that's got me stumpted:

I'm trying to replace the arrows that appear on either side of the image lightbox. They are currently created using type, but I need to replace these using images to be consistent with the rest of the site.

I've tried adding the images as I normally would using CSS, but it failed to display.

I'm not very experienced with Javascript so any tips on how to call images in CSS contained within Javascript would be gratefully received.

Here's a link to the code from the Javascript:

http://jsfiddle.net/tomperkins/TQDU7/

And here's a link to the plugin site if that helps:

http://galleria.aino.se/

Thanks in advance,

Tom Perkins

Comment: well i clicked `tidy up` in jsfiddle, much easier to read: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/TQDU7/1/

Comment: Could you include the CSS and HTML files in the jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

You just have to edit the "classic-map.png".. just make sure you map them in the same way ( put your button images at the same spot as the once already there )